# Drools - Agenda group not working as excepted

Tags: drools

Right now, in my drools project I have two groups of rules in separate DRL files which are split by agenda groups. For the agenda group "initial" I am setting auto focus to true for each rule in that agenda group.

```
rule "rule1"
    agenda-group "initial"
    auto-focus true
    salience 50
    when
        // condition1
    then
        //
end
```

For the other agenda group - "final" - the rules do NOT have the auto focus attribute set. Example:

```
rule "rule2"
    agenda-group "final"
    activation-group "group1"
    salience 0
    when
        // condition2
    then
        //
end
```

```
Below is the code snippet
 

val trigger(kieContainer: KieContainer) = {
       val kieSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession
       val commands = new BatchExecutoinCommandImpl()
       val agendaGroup = new AgendaGroupSetFocusCommand("initial")
       val agendaGroup1 = new AgendaGroupSetFocusCommand("final")
       executionCommand.addCommand(agendaGroup)
       executionCommand.addCommand(agendaGroup1)
       executionCommand.addCommand(CommandFactory.newInsert(customObject, 
       "obj"))
       kieSession.execute(commands)
    }
```

However, when the rules are executed, it seems like the rules in the "rule2" agenda group are being evaluated first. I have no idea why. I'm relatively new to drools, but I was sure this design would ensure the "rule1" rules would evaluate first.

Comment: Please show the code where you're firing the rules and calling `setFocus`.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas added..

Answer (score 0):

I also had this "strange" behavior recently, but the [Drools documentation](https://docs.drools.org/7.72.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_agenda_groups_for_rules) explains that the agenda groups are managed with a stack:

> Each time the setFocus() call is made in a Java application, the
> Drools engine adds the specified agenda group to the **top** of the rule
> stack

So with your current code, the "final" agenda group is given focus in **first**, since this is the **last** "AgendaGroupSetFocusCommand" you add in your command.

If you reverse the order of the "addCommand"s, you will have the expected behavior.